# MDX (how to have various Date Dimensions in a single X Axis?)

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2016

I have a cube containing facts each containing at least one Date Dimension :

Fact             :  Fact_Sales    , Fact_Leads        , Fact_Budget

Dimension Column :  FactorDateID  , LeadIssueDateID   , BudgetDateID

Now I need a Bar-chart with dates in X Axis and measures from all these facts in Y Axis (as Bar Values). Would you please guide me how to do that?

**I am forced to have all facts in a single cube and also i have to deploy different date usages for these different Dates(budgetdate,factordate,...) because they really differ from each other.

Comment: Do you mean you have three facts and Date dimension? I don't see any problems here. Could you please point a step you fail?

Comment: I have problem on defining a chart to show budget and sales as Y axis value, and Dates as X Axis Value. i can show sales by FactorDate, and budget by BudgetDate, but i dont know how to show them in a same chart. i should choose on of date dimensions as X Axis (for axample factordate) which is not able to devide other fact table measures(Budget Facts).
I want to know how to do that. is there any way by mdx code?or some way in rdl file designing?

Comment: Can't you create a Date dimension and make a relationship with all fact tables? I rather see visually what wrong is: could you please upload few screenshots in order to describe your issue?